# "Real" Resizing of Xamarin.Forms View

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I tried to make a ContentPage with a few ContentViews that are growing on tap (And layout its Children!).
That was working well with the LayoutTo(...) Method from Xamarin.Forms.ViewExtensions.
But I was getting some Issues with that, later I found [that Article](http://xfcomplete.net/xamarin.forms/2016/01/14/layoutto-doesnt-do-what-you-think-it-does/).

LayoutTo does not really resize the View, the view will reset to its initial position and size on the next LayoutCycle.
But I need to size a Small View to Fullscreen and use it like a normal ContentPage (with OnPropertyChanged)

What I tried so far:

- LayoutTo
- Forms Animation and set the Height/Width Request (and force Layout Cycle)
- Custom Renderer with UIView.Animate (and force Layout Cycle)
- Different Layouts (Absolute and Relative) with all combinations :-/
- ScaleTo

Has anyone tried similar things in Xamarin.Forms and can give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ScaleTo` method to resize View. Here is an example

```
async void Animate()
    {
        await Task.Delay (1000);
        await myCustomLabel.ScaleTo (10, 1000);
    }
```

Above snippet will wait for 1 second intitally then apply a 10x zoom to the `UILabel` with an animation lasting 1 second

Comment: The ScaleTo Method does not properly resize the Children of a View, such as labels. Its just "zooming in". Also it will not give me the possibility to define new Bounds.